# How to record and play voice in ios6 using HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios6

We are developing web application in HTML5 and Javascript.

We need to implement voice recording functionality.
We have used  [Wami Api](https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/) but it is not supporting on iPad as its using flash for recording.

Can you please give idea which is best option for recording voice in iPad in web application ?

Is there any API or library ?

Please suggest..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Phonegap and make it an app - that way you'll have access to some native APIs, like:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media

```
var media = new Media();

media.startRecord();
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.startRecord

Answer (score 0):

The (draft) standard for this is described in the [Media Capture and Streams specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/), but it is new, experimental and [iOS 6 does not support it](http://caniuse.com/#search=getUser).

If you want to record sound, then I think you will have to look at native applications rather than web applications.

You can continue to use HTML 5 / JavaScript for your application by using one of the various wrapper APIs that add interfaces to native features on mobile devices. For example, the [Media API from Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media) or [Titanium's AudioRecorder](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Media.AudioRecorder).